# Installing new Python packages that need to be compiled (using VS2013)

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm trying to install a Python package (named kerberos) that needs to be compiled. When I run `pip install kerberos` I receive this error message:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
```

However, I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional installed. I also have Python Tools 2.1 for Visual Studio 2013 installed. I've set up Visual Studio to use Python, and successfully executed a 'hello world' script (though that may not be relevant to the problem). What am I missing to get my package to install properly? Do I need something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need Visual Studio 2008 as described in the message.  Since Python was compiled with '08, trying to use another version is ill advised and can cause errors due to changes in the underlying C Libraries.  You can grab a copy of that from the link in your message.